# Rebuild on Jenkins If Target Branch on Azure DevOps is Updated

Tags: jenkins, tfs, azure-devops

My git Repository is Azure Dev-ops and I use Jenkins for Continuous Integration Build and I Use TFS Plugin for Jenkins.

I want to rebuild all open pull requests if the target branch (ex. master) is changed(ex. one of the opened pull requests was merged).

How Can Do It On Azure Dev-ops?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT ,I test your response but when i update target branch Azure Dev-ops doesn't send signal to Jenkins for rebuild PR. I understood on Azure There is a option in PR that let you Restart your Merge and based on your target branch can be updated. As soon as possible and i have a time i take a screenshot and explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In the pull request, if we change the Target branch, it will not trigger the pull request trigger.

As a workaround, we could create a service hooks->select Jenkins->selection A Code pushed->Then It will trigger build if the target branch is changed.

[image]